# Perceptron training - delta rule

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, perceptron

according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule), with the delta rule we adjust the weight by:

dw = alpha * (ti-yi)*g'(hj)xi

when alpha = learning constant, ti - true answer, yi - perceptron's guess,g' = the derivative of the activation function g with respect to the weighted sum of the perceptron's inputs, xi - input.

The part that I don't understand in this formula is the multiplication by the derivative g'. let g = sign(x) (the sign of the weighted sum). so g' is always 0, and dw = 0. However, in code examples I saw in the internet, the writers just omitted the g' and used the formula:

dw = alpha * (ti-yi)*(hj)xi

I will be glad to read a proper explanation!

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that if you use a step function for your activation function `g`, the gradient is always zero (except at 0), so the delta rule (aka gradient descent) just does nothing (`dw = 0`). This is why a step-function perceptron doesn't work well with gradient descent. :)

For a linear perceptron, you'd have `g'(x) = 1`, for `dw = alpha * (t_i - y_i) * x_i`.

You've seen code that uses `dw = alpha * (t_i - y_i) * h_j * x_i`. We can reverse-engineer what's going on here, because apparently `g'(h_j) = h_j`, which means remembering our calculus that we must have `g(x) = e^x + constant`. So apparently the code sample you found uses an exponential activation function.

This must mean that the neuron outputs are constrained to be on `(0, infinity)` (or I guess `(a, infinity)` for any finite `a`, for `g(x) = e^x + a`). I haven't run into this before, but I see some references online. [Logistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) or [tanh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh#Standard_algebraic_expressions) activations are more common for bounded outputs (either classification or regression with known bounds).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry, but I had a mistake, the code I saw used dw = alpha * (ti-yi)*x, which you referred to as "linear perceptron". Yet, this code used sign function as an activation function, although it's not linear...I am little confused.

Comment: This sounds like the code is wrong. If you point us to it maybe we can figure out that it's doing something else, though.

Comment: It can't be wrong, because it works. [Here](http://glowingpython.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/perceptron.html) is the code.

Comment: _Wrong_ and _works_ aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. In this case, the code isn't actually using the delta rule, which as we've noted doesn't work for step-function activations. Instead, it's doing the classical [perceptron algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron_algorithm), which works (in the sense that if the data is linearly separable it will converge to a separating hyperplane), but isn't an implementation of [gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) as the delta rule is. (That doesn't necessarily mean it's worse, just a different model.)